# autossh won't run in background

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I try to set autossh to run at boot adding it to /etc/rc.local but I am unable to even get it to run in the background.

This is the crucial part of my config file:

```
Host remotehost.com
  LocalForward 127.0.0.1:8082 127.0.0.1:8082
  LocalForward 127.0.0.1:8000 127.0.0.1:80
  LocalForward 127.0.0.1:10001 127.0.0.1:10001
  LocalForward 127.0.0.1:12001 127.0.0.1:12001
  Port 9922
```

This command works:

```
autossh -F /home/[username]/.ssh/config -i /home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa remotehost.com
```

But, if I add the -f option

```
autossh -f -F /home/[username]/.ssh/config -i /home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa remotehost.com
```

it won't.

As you see I am only using absolute pathes so it should not be [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/534229/autossh-in-background-does-not-work).

This is what my log says:

```
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: checking for grace period, tries = 0
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: starting ssh (count 1)
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: ssh child pid is 4368
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: check on child 4368
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: set alarm for 600 secs
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4368]: execing /usr/bin/ssh
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: check on child 4368
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: ssh exited with status 0; autossh exiting
2014/04/22 12:09:07 autossh[4367]: expired child, returning 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Silly me. This is covered in the manual even though I missed it. I should have added the `-N`-switch. This is what I put in in rc.local and which works:

```
su [username] -c 'autossh -f -N -F /home/[username]/.ssh/config_tunnels -i /home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa remotehost.com
```

`[username]` is of course exchanged with my username.